# I/UrlLauncher(17669): component name for (url) is null

Tags: flutter, dart

Why does it throw an error and give me the link is empty even though the link exists?
And when I use launch (url) alone, the link opens without any problems.

[image]

```
 String StateUrl = 'View App' ;
 var url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-k0IXjCHObw' ;
body: Column(
        children: [
          Text(StateUrl),
          Center(
            child: ElevatedButton.icon(
                onPressed: () async{
                  try {
                    await canLaunch(url) ?
                    await launch(url):
                    throw 'Error';
                  } catch(e){
                    setState(() {
                      StateUrl = e.toString() ;
                    });
                  }
                },
                icon: const Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.link),
                label:  const Text('View Url')
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Performing hot reload:

> D/EGL_emulation(17669): app_time_stats: avg=17852.65ms min=658.78ms
> max=35046.52ms count=2 I/UrlLauncher(17669): component name for
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-k0IXjCHObw is null
> D/EGL_emulation(17669): app_time_stats: avg=8279.72ms min=8279.72ms
> max=8279.72ms count=1

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You have to add `<queries>` elements to your **AndroidManifest.xml** file.
[more info](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher#android)

Comment: adding <queries/> tag inside manifest and removing canLaunch(url) check resolved the issue for me

Answer (score 19):

With link can handle via other app like youtube, spreadsheets, document...

from android 11 (API 30) and above you must add this permission to `AndroidManifest.xml`

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />
```

Or query what you need:

```xml
<queries>
   <package android:name="net.com.example" /> // your android package name
</queries>
```

**UPDATE:**
with QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES, you will need to explain to Google Play side when you publish the app.

To avoid that, you need to query what you need:
`package`,`intent`...

please refer:
https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/declaring

Comment: This solution works, but when you publish on Google Play, it produce a permission problem that you have to manage it before they let you publish the app. Better solution for @JRJR. You can add this in your manifest for https schema:  <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent>
    </queries>

Comment: adding permission worked for me

Answer (score 16):

try using
`await launch(url);`
instead of
`if (await canLaunch(url)) { print("launching $url"); await launch(url); } else { throw 'Could not launch maps'; }`
it seems theres a problem with canLaunch(url) function

Answer (score 9):

Don't use `canLaunch` with videos URL, just use `try/catch`.

Answer (score 4):

If you come here looking for why your email link (`mailto:email@example.com`) doesn't work, then try this out.

#### Don't call `canLaunch` for `mailto` links - use it only for `http` and `https`!

Since I have both `http(s)` and `mailto` links in my app, I use the `try-catch` block.

Here is the full function:

```dart
class UrlHandler {
  /// Attempts to open the given [url] in in-app browser. Returns `true` after successful opening, `false` otherwise.
  static Future<bool> open(String url) async {
    try {
      await launch(
        url,
        enableJavaScript: true,
      );
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      log(e.toString());
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As per https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/use-cases

Add the below code in the Android Manifest for Internet Browsing Permissions

```
<!-- Place inside the <queries> element. -->
<intent>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:scheme="https" />
</intent>
```

Answer (score 2):

for me the solution is
to copy and paste

```
<!-- Provide required visibility configuration for API level 30 and above -->
<queries>
  <!-- If your app checks for SMS support -->
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="sms" />
  </intent>
  <!-- If your app checks for call support -->
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="tel" />
  </intent>
</queries>
```

from official packages docs
but the problem is that the package removed the next lines from code snippet

```
<intent>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:scheme="https" />
</intent>
```

so add them first to the

Answer (score 2):

**canLaunch(url)** was the problem and try catch could not catch the exception in my case so I used **onError** method.

```
                launchUrl(Uri.parse(url)).onError(
                  (error, stackTrace) {
                    print("Url is not valid!");
                    return false;
                  },
                );
```

Answer (score 1):

To use `canLaunch` for mailto links, add this query to the AndroidManifest.xml:

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myapp.my_app">
   <application
        <!-- ... -->
    </application>

    <!-- Provide required visibility configuration for API level 30 and above -->
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="mailto" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>
```

Then, set up the Url like:

```dart
  final Uri url = Uri(
    scheme: 'mailto',
    path: inputUrl,
  );

  try {
    if (await canLaunchUrl(url)) {
      await launchUrl(url, mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    // Handle
  }
```

This code will make those functions work for email links.

Answer (score 0):

Try is like this:

```
try {
  if(await canLaunch(url)) await launch(url):
   } catch(e){
   setState(() {
   StateUrl = e.toString() ;
    });
throw e;}
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code, it works for me:

```
_launchURL() async {
  const url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_mass_index';
  if (await launch(url)) {
    await canLaunch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```

and use this `_launchURL()` function in `onPressed();`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. The solution was so set an intent in the android manifest file. If this is done, the `canLaunch()` call will not fail, cause you allow the android system to query this url.

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data  android:scheme="https" android:host="youtube.com" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

For comparison, the url launcher now prints following text to the console:

`I/UrlLauncher( 2628): component name for <your youtube link> is {com.google.android.youtube/com.google.android.youtube.UrlActivity}`

Further if you set the launchMode to `LaunchMode.externalApplication` the youtube app will launch, if installed.

Also Google updates his [PolicyBytes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O0UwUF2DgQc) and I think using

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />`

or

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />`

might lead to app rejects, if you can not explain in detail why you need to use those permissions.

Comment: It's work for me ;<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />

Answer (score 0):

The url_launcher requires a Uri object to be passed instead of a string.  Add a Uri.parse

```html
String StateUrl = 'View App' ;
 var url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-k0IXjCHObw' ;
body: Column(
        children: [
          Text(StateUrl),
          Center(
            child: ElevatedButton.icon(
                onPressed: () async{
                  try {
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                    await canLaunch(uri) ?
                    await launch(uri):
                    throw 'Error';
                  } catch(e){
                    setState(() {
                      StateUrl = e.toString() ;
                    });
                  }
                },
                icon: const Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.link),
                label:  const Text('View Url')
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I just used this and it worked...(nb:Dec 2022)

```
if (!await launchUrl(url)) {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to add "http://" or "https://" before your url String. It works for me.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `await launch(url);` instead of

```
if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    print("launching $url"); 
    await launch(url);
} 
else { 
    throw 'Could not launch maps'; 
}
```

It seems theres a problem with `canLaunch(url)` function

Thank you for this Solution :)

Comment: Could you reformat your code a bit to make it more readable?