# why flutter give me url null in url launcher?

Tags: flutter, url, launcher

```dart
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () async {
    const url ='https://www.facebook.com';

    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url,forceWebView: true,enableJavaScript: true);
    } else {
      // can't launch url
    }
  },
);
```

```
I/UrlLauncher( 7566): component name for https://www.facebook.com is null
```

Comment: if I'm not mistaken, it happens on Android 11 and MacOS Bigsur

Comment: check this Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66762732/17180860 , i think it will help

Comment: Please refer to this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70224911/i-urllauncher17669-component-name-for-url-is-null

Answer (score 8):

Add the queries for each platform, follow the documentation in this link [URL Launcher API Reference](https://pub.dev/documentation/url_launcher/latest/)

**iOS**
Add any URL schemes passed to canLaunchUrl as LSApplicationQueriesSchemes entries in your Info.plist file.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
  <string>https</string>
  <string>http</string>
</array>
```

**Android**
Starting from API 30 Android requires package visibility configuration in your AndroidManifest.xml otherwise canLaunchUrl will return false. A  element must be added to your manifest as a child of the root element.

```
<queries>
  <!-- If your app opens https URLs -->
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
  </intent>
  <!-- If your app makes calls -->
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
    <data android:scheme="tel" />
  </intent>
  <!-- If your sends SMS messages -->
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
    <data android:scheme="smsto" />
  </intent>
  <!-- If your app sends emails -->
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
  </intent>
</queries>
```

This works for me!