# Flutter Map Not opening on android

Tags: android, flutter, google-maps-android-api-2

```
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher_string.dart';
class MapsUtils{
MapsUtils._();
static Future<void> openMapWithPosition(double latitude, double longitude) async{
String googleMapUrl = "https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=$latitude,$longitude";
if(await canLaunchUrlString(googleMapUrl))
{
  await launchUrlString(googleMapUrl);
}
else
{
  throw "Could not open the map.";
}}
static Future<void> openMapWithAddress(String fullAddress) async {
String query = Uri.encodeComponent(fullAddress);
String googleMapUrl = "https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=$query";

if(await canLaunchUrlString(googleMapUrl))
{
  await launchUrlString(googleMapUrl);
}
else
{
  throw "Could not open the map.";
}  } }
```

**This is my code for opening maps on android using flutter. I have added all the required dependencies i.e. URL_launcher but it's not working. **

I/UrlLauncher(13043): component name for https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=18.6446934,73.7615529 is null
I/UrlLauncher(13043): component name for https://flutter.dev is null
E/flutter (13043): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: Could not open the map.
E/flutter (13043): #0      MapsUtils.openMapWithPosition (package:user/maps/maps.dart:25:7)
E/flutter (13043): 
E/flutter (13043):

I am getting above error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I/UrlLauncher(17669): component name for (url) is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70224911/i-urllauncher17669-component-name-for-url-is-null)

Answer (score 1):

From **android 11** (API 30) and above, you must add `QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES` permission to `AndroidManifest.xml`

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />
```

refer to the following link for more information:
https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/declaring

Answer (score 0):

For the android device to run `canLaunchUrl` or `canLaunchUrlString`, you need to add these to the AndroidManifest.xml:

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myapp.my_app">
   <application
        <!-- ... -->
    </application>

    <!-- Provide required visibility configuration for API level 30 and above -->
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="mailto" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>
```

This code will make those functions work for web links and email links.